# Solr : file entity processor and delta import

Tags: solr, apache-tika, dataimporthandler, delta-index

I'm using solr 3.3 and i want to use delta import with file entity processor and tika entity processor. Full import works fine but the delta import parameter doesn't import the new documents.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Changing following values in the data-config.xml will solved the problem

**${dih.last_index_time}** instead **${dataimporter.last_index_time}**

**${dih.delta.id}** instead **${dataimporter.delta.id}** .

Answer (score 0):

Delta import works the same as Full import, except that it loads the data after the last build.
Delta import uses the same entities with the relationships, so there should not be any difference.
Do the records get picked up ? Are there any errors ?

Comment: There is no errors but it imports all documents. I would like it imports new documents.

Comment: Does your delta query check for the last build time which will help to it pick up the new documents added e.g. where last_modified > '${dataimporter.last_index_time}'